# Please help me identify this silvery green leaved ground cover

Tags: identification

There are dozens of these plants in my yard (zone 6, a few miles from the coast). I like that they are low and can be walked on, but I want to know what they are.

The plants have been receiving full sun all summer with a drought. There seems to be one central place that all the vines grow from. The vines grow along the ground, spreading out from that central place. They have not grown upward onto any of my trees. I have not observed flowers. The leaves are a silvery green, less than one inch, smooth, and narrow.

[image: close up of the plant showing the leaves]

[image: picture from 1-2 feet away showing the vines]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Polygonum arenastrum (knotweed, knotgrass)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonum_arenastrum) is a common introduced annual plant in North America, where it can be confused with [Euphorbia maculata](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euphorbia_maculata). The latter contains milky sap in the stem.

Confirmed by https://identify.plantnet.org/ with a likelihood of 83%.

I think the photo shows flower buds in the corners of the leaves.

Comment: Thanks! And thanks for the link. I had found apps that do the same thing but require a subscription.